# How to get the path to the puppet.conf in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, puppet

I want to write a ruby script that is called from command line.

The script needs to load a configuration from a yaml file. The yaml file is in the Folder of the puppet.conf.

In an custom function of puppet I can get the folder with

```
File.dirname(Puppet.settings[:config])
```

Unfortunately "Puppet" is unknown for the script.

Is it possible to load "Puppet" in the script or to get this path in any other way?

---EDIT---

I forgot to mention that this script runs on a puppetmaster and not on a puppetagent. Maybe that matters...

Answer (score 0):

You could probably load the Puppet library by calling

```
require 'puppet'
```

before calling `Puppet`.

Comment: I'm afraid but that doesn't work. I get the following error: Puppet::Settings::InterpolationError: Error converting value for param 'config': Could not find value for $confdir

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Solved the problem temporarily with static path.